# How to compile and bundle react 16.9 using gulp 4.0.1?

Tags: gulp-4, react-16

I have an existing project, I used `React 16.9`. Now, I want to implement `Gulp 4.0.1` to build it in the server. I am running in windows 10.

In my components, I am using `import` `form`

**I tried using this gulpfile.js, its very simple**.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  browserify = require('browserify'),
  source = require('vinyl-source-stream'),
  buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');

var BUILD_DIR = 'buildtest/';

function compile() {
  var bundler = browserify('src/index.js');

  return bundler
    .transform('babelify', { presets: ['es2015', 'react'] })
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('index.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(BUILD_DIR));
}

gulp.task('build:js', function() {
  return compile();
})

gulp.task('build', ['build:js'])
```

Now by running the `gulp` command it gives me this error:

```
λ gulp
assert.js:350
    throw err;
    ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
    at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (D:\myprojectfolderpath\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:10:3)
    at Gulp.task (D:\myprojectfolderpath\node_modules\undertaker\lib\task.js:13:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\myprojectfolderpath\gulpfile.js:84:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
```

Comment: Try `gulp build`. The `build` over here is *task* name => `Task function must be specified`

Comment: @Mr_Green I run the `gulp build` its still giving me the same error. thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

According to the gulp's task [Documentation](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/task) `gulp.task([taskName], taskFunction)` second argument the 'taskFunction' needs to use either a `gulp.series()` or `gulp.parallel`.

Before 4.0 it was possible to define the task as you did, but this changed in 4.0.

Changing your `gulp.task('build', ['build:js'])` into `gulp.task('build', gulp.series('build:js'))` should fix the issue.